# Determining the UMVUE for a discrete scaled uniform sample.

Tags: probability, statistics

I would greatly appreciate some help. Below, I'll try to explain what I want to do and show my progress.

To begin with, let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n} \sim \mathrm{unif}\{1, 2, \dots, N\}$. Let $T = X_{(n)} = \max\{X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}\}$. It is easily shown that $T$ is a sufficient and complete statistic for $\theta = N$. My goal is to try and find the UMVUE for $N$.

**Approach:**

I am interested in computing $E[T]$ so that I can determine a function $f(T)$ for which $E_{N}f(T) = N$, which would (by sufficiency and completeness of $T$) be the UMVUE for $\theta = N$.

**Progress:**

I would like to determine the probability mass function of $T$. That is $$p_{N}(t) = P_{N}(T = t) = F_{N}(t) - F_{N}(t-1)$$

Notice that $F_{N}(t)= \left( \frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{N} \right)^{n} I_{[0,\theta]}(t)$. Also, if $\lfloor t \rfloor = k$, then $\lfloor t-1 \rfloor = k-1$, and so

$$P_{N}(T=t) = \left( \frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{N} \right)^{n} - \left( \frac{\lfloor t - 1 \rfloor}{N} \right)^{n} = \left( \frac{k^{n} - (k-1)^{n}}{N^{n}} \right)$$

At this point, I use the binomial theorem to rewrite the numerator. Thus

$$ P_{N}(T=t) = \frac{1}{N^{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} k^{n-i} $$

Beyond this, I simplified things with Wolfram to get

$$P_{N}(T=t)= \left( \frac{k}{N} \right)^{n} \left( 1 - \left( \frac{k-1}{k} \right)^{n}\right)$$

**Difficulty:**

Given any of these expressions for the probability mass function, I don't see how I can compute $$E[T] = \sum_{k=1}^{N} kP_{N}(T = k)$$ Is there anywhere left to go with my approach?

**EDIT:** I have managed to find that $E[T]$ should satisfy $$\frac{1}{N^{n}} \left( 1 - 2^{n} - 3^{n} - \dots - (N-1)^{n} + N^{n+1} \right)$$

I'm not sure if this has a closed-form solution.

Comment: Just a comment: in the real German tank situation, the $X_i$ are not independent, since if say $X_1=42$, then no other $X_i$ can be $42$. If $n$ is much smaller than $N$, you could pretend the $X_i$ are independent. Maybe none of this matters depending on the analysis.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'll edit the title now. I suppose I'm just trying to find the UMVUE of a (discrete) scaled uniform sample.

Comment: For the UMVUE, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944781/prove-effiency-of-this-discrete-uniform-distribution-estimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about continuing your approach, but it seems intuitive that $E[T]\approx\frac{n}{n+1}N$, if you imagine spreading out the $n$ tanks over the $N$ possibilities. Let's see if I can justify:

$P(T=k)$ is easy enough to write a formula for. The max from the sample is $k$, and all other tanks are smaller.  So $$P(T=k)=\frac{\begin{array}{c}\text{number of samples that have one member at $k$}\\{\text{and the remaining $n-1$ coming from below $k$}}\end{array}}{\text{number of possible samples of size $n$}}=\frac{\binom{k-1}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

This is even valid for $k<n$, since it outputs $0$. So 
 $$
\begin{align}
E[T]&=\sum_{k=1}^Nk\frac{\binom{k-1}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}}\sum_{k=1}^Nk\binom{k-1}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k!}{(n-1)!(k-n)!}\\
&=\frac{n}{\binom{N}{n}}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}\\
&=\frac{n}{\binom{N}{n}}\sum_{k=1}^N\binom{k}{n}\\
&=\frac{n}{\binom{N}{n}}\binom{N+1}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{n}{n+1}(N+1)
\end{align}$$

pretty close to the intuitive guess.

Comment: In hindsight, I think this was an easier computation than what you are trying _because_ it treats the problem as sampling rather than with independent variables. The binomial coefficients and the identities used make things easier to sum than the powers of expressions that you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm familiar with the approach you gave, but I was trying to get at it another way. It turns out that I was interested in the problem where we assume sampling is done with replacement, whereas yours assumes that sampling is without replacement. But I appreciate the effort you put into this so I'll accept this answer (given that I did not give a clear idea on the assumptions I was operating under). Thanks.